# According to Jehovah's Witnesses, what is "these seventy years" refering to in Zechariah 1:12 and Zechariah 7:1-5?

Tags: exegesis, jehovahs-witnesses, chronology, zechariah

> So the angel of Jehovah said: “O Jehovah of armies, how long will you withhold your mercy from Jerusalem and the cities of Judah, with whom you have been indignant **these 70 years**?” ([Zechariah 1:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/38/1#study=discover&v=38:1:12), NWT)

> <sup>**1**</sup> And in the fourth year of King Darius, the word of Jehovah came to Zechariah on the fourth day of the ninth month, that is, the month of Chislev. <sup>**2**</sup>  The people of Bethel sent Sharezer and Regem-melech and his men to beg for the favor of Jehovah, <sup>**3**</sup>  saying to the priests of the house of Jehovah of armies and to the prophets: **“Should I weep in the fifth month and abstain from food, as I have done for so many years?”**
> <sup>**4**</sup> The word of Jehovah of armies again came to me, saying: <sup>**5**</sup> “Say to all the people of the land and to the priests, ‘When you fasted and wailed in the fifth month and in the seventh month for **70 years**, did you really fast for me? ([Zechariah 7:1-5](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/38/7#study=discover&v=38:7:1-38:7:5), NWT)

I have a copy of "Aid to Bible Understanding", WBTS, 1971, an encyclopedia of the Watchtower. On page 422 under "[Darius](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200011096#h=31-33)" it says:

> It is particularly with regard to the rebuilding of the temple at Jerusalem that Darius Hystaspis [Darius the Great, Darius I] figures in the Bible record.... it continued stopped until the second year of Darius (520/519). ... During this year the prophets Haggai and Zechariah stirred up the Jews to renew the construction ... the temple work went on to successful completion by the "sixth year of the reign of Darius" (Ezra 6:15).. by March 5/6 of 515 BCE.

All of the above dates are in agreement with Parker & Dubberstein's standard work on the chronology of the period, and  present no problem to me as an evangelical.

The event recorded in Zech 1:7-12 can be dated via Parker & Dubberstein to 9th Feb 519 BC, Gregorian date; and Zech 7:1-5 can be dated to 2nd/3rd Dec 518 BC, Gregorian.

The temple of Jerusalem was destroyed at the same time as the city, Jer 52:12-14.

If the temple was destroyed in 587 BC per as the Catholic chronologist Valerius Coucke and the evangelical chronologist Rodger c. Young (cf rcyoung.org) then it is easy to understand the meaning of "these seventy years", and easy to understand why the enquirers should be asking the prophet whether it is OK to stop fasting in 518 when the temple rebuild is nearing completion.

But if the temple was destroyed in 607 BCE - as per the articles at the end of this question - then in 518 BCE, not seventy, but nearly ninety years have elapsed.

So my question is 'How do Jehovah's Witnesses explain "these seventy years" in these passages in Zechariah?'

- [Part 1: Watchtower, October 1, 2011, page 26](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2011736)
- [Part 2: Watchtower, November 1, 2011, page 22](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2011810)

Comment: Click on zec1:12 in the nwt link.  It brings up resources explaining the verse including “Paradise Restored, pp. 130-132”

Comment: @User14 - Sorry, I do not know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Your nwt link to zec1:12.  Tap on the vs number 12 it will pull up reference material that yiu can use to find answers

Comment: @User14 - Thanks

Comment: @lesley sure good question.  The jw.org website is readily available to anyone who really wants an answer to a doctrinal question. So that is the best place to go if you really have a sincere question and simply want an answer.  This site used to be moderated much better and one could give an answer get a few upvotes and move on.  Now however nearly every question aimed at JWs is a vehicle for the asker to engage in debate in comments.  That is tiresome and pointless.

Comment: @Lesley have you used the jw library app?  https://www.jw.org/en/online-help/jw-library/

Comment: @User14 - What's an Android device?  I don't think I've got one.  Certainly don't have an Apple device.  Is this stuff for my mobile phone?  If so, I have to confess I wouldn't know how to download software applications onto my mobile phone if my life depended on it!